# SBT and Multimodule project in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I come from Eclipse and I don't undertand how I can organize my projects in Intellj.

I have read the documentation and understand than project is similar to workspace and module to eclipse project.

I want to create a  SBT project with many modules, but there's just one SBT and the dependencies of my modules are different so I want that my ModuleA only has its dependencias and ModuleB the same.

What's the way to manage these kind of things with IntellJ?
I have read http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html this page, but I don't know if IntellJ manages these things.

Comment: I recommend setting up your project outside of IntelliJ completely.  Once that's done, you should just be able to import the project normally (as an SBT project) and IntelliJ should automatically understand your dependencies.  If you're having trouble with this, try upgrading to the latest version of IntelliJ + SBT plugin -- there have been a lot of improvements related to Scala/SBT support in the last year.

Comment: I guess that I have the last version.. I' using IntellJ 15.

Comment: To use SBT projects in IntelliJ IDEA, you only need the Scala plugin. With this, using file -> open je can select the directory containing your build.sbt file or your project folder. IntelliJ will then provide you with a popup with some project specific settings. When this form is filled out, IntelliJ will generate the appropriate project files for you.